# Jquery plugin Chosen not working on AJAX Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-chosen

I have two drop downs. First one contains mobile networks MTN , VODACOM , TELKOM and the second is a chosen multiselect dropdown which should contain data (cell numbers) populated via AJAX based on the mobile network above. but it is not firing  after an AJAX call.

```
     <div id="network" class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label">Mobile Network</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="network" name="network">  
         <option id="MTN" value="MTN">MTN</option>
         <option id="VODACOM" value="VODACOM">VODACOM</option>  
         <option id="TELKOM" value="TELKOM">TELKOM</option>       
       </select>
     </div>
```

And the second one contain cell numbers based on what is selected from above. and the dropdown uses the Chosen Plugin

```
     <div id="cellNumber" class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label">Select SIMs</label>
        <select multiple class="chosen-select form-control" id="cellNumber" name="cellNumber[]">
       </select>
     </div>
```

On the page i do this

```
<script>   
  $("select.chosen-select").chosen(); //Initializing the plugin

     $('select#network').change(function () {
       var id = $('select#network').children(':selected').attr('id');

         if(id != " "){
          localStorage.clear();
           AJAXCallNumbersByCarrier(id);   //AJAX Call
          }
        });

</script>
```

And this is the AJAX

```
 function AJAXCallNumbersByCarrier(data) {
   var url = "/number/" + encodeURI(data) + "/carrier";
   var type = "GET";

   jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content')
  }
});
jQuery.ajax({
url: url,
type: type,
data: {
  "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content')
},
beforeSend: function () { },
success: function (data) {
  try {
    var count = data.length;
    if (count > 0) {
      var id = $('#cellNumber').attr('id');

      $('select#cellNumber').empty();

      var numbers = "<option value='' hidden=''>[Select SIMs]</option>";
      for (var index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        details = data[index];
        id = details['cellnumber'];
        cellnumber = details['cellnumber'];
        simserial = details['simserial'];
        realm = details['apnname'];
        numbers += '<option id="' + id + '" value="' + cellnumber + '">'+'[ '+ cellnumber + ' ] [ ' + simserial + ' ] [ ' + realm + ' ]' + '</option>';

      }
      $('select#cellNumber').append(numbers);
      $('div#cellNumber').show();
    }else{

      $('div#ErrorMessage').empty();
      $('div#ErrorMessage').append("No numbers available for the selected customer");
      $('div#ErrorMessage').show();
      $('div.alert').not('.alert-important').delay(3000).fadeOut(350);
      $('select#cellNumber').empty();
      $('select#cellNumber').append("<option value'' hidden=''>[No numbers available for the selected customer]</option>");
      $('div#cellNumber').show();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    alert("Error running JS code from module: AJAXCallNumbersByCarrier");
  }
},
error: function (url, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert("url: " + url + " error: " + jqXHR.responseText + " status: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
},
complete: function () { }
});
   }
```

When i remove the $("select.chosen-select").chosen(); it works fine as a normal HTML multi select dropdown. The issue is the chosen. It is not firing. Data is empty. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try to reinitialize the chosen in the success function like

```
success:function(data){
   // your code here
   $('select#cellNumber').append(numbers);
   $("select.chosen-select").chosen(); 
   $('div#cellNumber').show();
}
```

it solved once i face the same issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used Select2 instead. works well.